# sql query with changing month

Tags: mysql

I need to query a database which will return the number of people subscribed to a particular service during that month.
I use the below  query

```
select  subscriberid, count(*) from ABC where updated time like '2013-05-%' ;
```

In this query I need to update the `Updatedtime` field to be `2013-06-%` when the next month comes and then 07 when the next to next month comes. I want the query to be updated automatically when the next month comes instead of manually changing it every time.

Also note that I want the data for a particular month at a time, so please don't suggest grouping by month as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it

```
SELECT subscriberid, COUNT(*) 
  FROM ABC 
 WHERE  YEAR(updated_time) =  YEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND MONTH(updated_time) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT subscriberid, COUNT(*) 
  FROM ABC 
 WHERE updated_time BETWEEN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1) 
                        AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work fine:

```
SELECT 
    subscriberid, 
    count(*) 
from 
    ABC 
where 
    updatedtime LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m'), '-%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
 SELECT subscriberid, count(*) as total
 FROM ABC 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(updated_time, "%Y-%m") = "2013-05";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT subscribersid, updated, COUNT(*) from subscribers 
   WHERE YEAR(updated) = YEAR(NOW()) 
      AND MONTH(updated) = MONTH(NOW())
```

You can see it working in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67131/2)

Hope this helps